# What is the proper Settings for Session Validation - Magento 2.1.0-rc3

Tags: magento2, magento2.1.0

ON the backend Store>Configurations>General>Web we have the "Session Validation Settings" which shows these options:

**Validate REMOTE_ADDR:** NO

**Validate HTTP_VIA:** NO

**Validate HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR:** NO

**Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT:** NO

**Use SID on Storefront:** YES

Everything came for default as it is, what is the recommended options to choose?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 12):

From http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/stores/security-session-validation.html?Highlight=Session%20Validation

> 1. To verify that the IP address of a request matches what is stored
>      in the $_SESSION variable, set Validate REMOTE_ADDR to “Yes.”
> 2. To verify that the proxy address of an incoming request matches
>      what is stored in the $_SESSION variable, set Validate HTTP_VIA to
>      “Yes.”
> 3. To verify that the forwarded-for address of a request matches
>      what is stored in the $_SESSION variable, set Validate
>      HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR to “Yes.”
> 4. To verify that the browser or device that is used to access the
>      store during a session matches what is stored in the $_SESSION
>      variable, set Validate HTTP_USER_AGENT to “Yes.”
> 5. If you want a user to stay logged in while switching between
>      stores, set Use SID on Frontend to “Yes.” If including SID with
>      analytics, you must configure your analytics software to filter the
>      SID from URLs, so the page visit counts are correct.

**As ever it is a balance between security and convenience.**

- 1&2 mean the request must come from the same ip/through the same
  proxy. This means an attacker can't just simply spoof the session. It also
  means if your customer is on a mobile device and moves from wifi to celular
  they also loose their session.
- 3 refers to this header https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For. It says that the declared originating i.p. (before any proxies) must be the same. This has the same potential issues as 1&2.
- 4 makes sure the device/browser hasn't changed. This is probably OK most of the time but is easy to spoof.
- 5 Depends on your setup.

You can see why the first 3 aren't enabled by default. I would leave it as it is.

Comment: then as per your comment about 1&2 , its safe if i enable/set this option YES ?