# The Shopping cart is being shared by visitors

Tags: magento-1.8, login, security, shopping-cart

I am having several serious problems on the site and I do not know what the reason may be.
I looked at several topics and did not see who had the same problem. I am not an expert, I bought a template for over a year and now I have seen the problem.

Examples of serious errors on my site:

1) The Shopping cart is being shared by visitors on different computers. (Eg if I add in my computer and / or a friend to refresh or add more articles in his computer, both see the articles entering or leaving the cart)

2) More serious, if I log in with my account, and my friend on his home computer click on the shopping cart or refresh the browser it will also enter my account. (It comes into my account.)

What can it be?

My Magento version is 1.8.1

Comment: more likely its a Session issue. Check your server settings and configurations.

Comment: We could do with some more information about your setup, do you have varnish sat in front of your server? What cacheing systems are you using, where are your sessions stored, files, db, redis etc.

Comment: im using linux / cpanel. Where can i see this settings? Thank you.

Comment: DanCarlyon - the cache is the default of magento 1.8.1 (i think). no varnish founded. Thank you

Comment: Where are your sessions stored? files, db, redis?

Comment: What are your Cookie and Session settings? Have you checked to make sure the directories have proper permissions and aren't blindly dumping into a subfolder you don't have access to?

Comment: You might be interested in adjusting your session validation settings, see this answer here: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/156617/231 You could try to add the user agent to your session validation settings.

Comment: See also the official documentation: http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/session-validation.html

Comment: DanCarlyon - Its stored in db.

Comment: Anna Völkl - Thanks, i tried that validations and its not working yet.